# With KSH, how to convert “12345” to “1.2.3.4.5?”

Tags: unix, shell, shell-script, ksh

With KSH, if I have a string `12345` and I want to it be converted to `1.2.3.4.5`, how can I do that?

I tried to use `cut` but it's not straightforward.

```
echo "12345" | cut -c1
```

Comment: You should be more specific. What do you want to do? Put a period between every combination of two digits in a variable? Put a period between every two characters on every line in a file? Put a period after the first four characters of all lines of standard input consisting of unseparated digits? Etc...

Answer (score 2):

Obligatory `awk` answer:

```sh
echo "12345" | awk '$1=$1' FS= OFS="."
```

Output is:

```sh
1.2.3.4.5
```

Answer is modified from one of the solutions in [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8696813/117259) post.

Comment: I tried it on Solaris and found that I have to use nawk or /usr/xpg4/bin/awk otherwise it returns error message like below.
# echo "12345" | awk '$1=$1' FS= OFS="."
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: Then I tried to use # echo "12345" | /usr/xpg4/bin/awk '$1=$1' FS= OFS=".", however, the result is 12345 other than the expected 1.2.3.4.5 Can you advice? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Awk syntax is quite finicky between versions. Any luck with `nawk`? I've found that this works on BSD `awk`, but not GNU `awk`.

Comment: Same result for nawk. Actually, I figure out another way: echo "1234" | sed 's/\(.\{1\}\)/\1./g'. However the result is "1.2.3.4."  I have to remove last . so the whole command line is: 
# temp_str=`echo "1234" | sed 's/\(.\{1\}\)/\1./g'`
# echo "${temp_str%?}"

Answer (score 1):

Perl regex (with lookups and backreferences) answer to replace everything by everything-plus-a-dot except for the last one (assuming that's what the question was):

```sh
$ echo "12345" | perl -wlpe 's/(.(?=.))/$1\./g'
1.2.3.4.5
```

Comment: This one is great! However, I want to just do it with awk or seed

Answer (score 0):

A sed solution tested with ksh and /usr/bin/sed on OpenSolaris

```sh
echo "12345" | /usr/bin/sed -e 's/./&\./g' -e 's/\.$//'
```